# How do I pass a function with an argument to on_press?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm writing a simple mobile app that parses information from the site and displays it on the screen. But the problem is that when I click the button, all widgets should be removed and only the text that I parsed from the site should remain. To do this I should pass to the function `on_press` the argument of my `BoxLayout`, but it just doesn't work.
Code:

```py
class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        bl = MyBoxLayout(orientation='vertical', padding=[5], spacing=10)
        bl.add_widget(MyButton(text='И. С. Тургенев. «Отцы и дети»', on_press = self.btn_press(bl)))

    

def btn_press(self,bl):
    bl.clear_widgets()
    sc = MyScrollView(size_hint=(1, None))
    x = 1
    data = ''
    while True:
        if x == 1:
            url = "http://loveread.ec/read_book.php?id=12021&p=1"
        elif x < 5:
            url = "http://loveread.ec/read_book.php?id=12021&p=" + f'{x}'
        else:
            break
        request = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, "html.parser")
        teme = soup.find_all("p", class_="MsoNormal")
        for temes in teme:
            data += temes.text
            print(temes.text)
        x = x + 1
    bl.add_widget(Label(text=data, color=(0, 0, 0, 1),font_size = 17,halign='left',
                        valign='top'))
    sc.add_widget(bl)
    return sc
```

Also I have a lot of errors with outputting ScrollView. (Please help me as a newbie)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically when you're passing a function as an argument, the intent is that you want the function to be called *later*, in response to some event.

In such cases, you want to pass only the function *name*, without the parentheses, like so:

```
on_press = self.btn_press
```

If you include the parentheses, as you did in your example, the function is called *immediately* which isn't what you want.

Comment: When you want to bind an argument at this point in time, you can use a lambda to do so:

on_press = ()=>self.btn_press(bl)

Comment: Then how do I pass bl to clear all widgets?

Comment: and can you explain why i dont see a scrollview with my code? I didnt see mistake in my code(